OneNote COM Add-In Not Loading - Runtime Error occured during the loading of the COM Add-In
I am developing a COM Add-In for OneNote for Microsoft Office 365 MSO using this project(VanillaAddIn) as a template. However, when I build and install the project, I get the following error when I try to load the Add-In from OneNote.
Load Behavior: Not Loaded. A runtime error occured during the loading of the COM Add-In
I have tried adding a call to start the debugger on the OnStartupComplete method, but the debugger isn't being launched so I assume something is failing before any of the code even runs.
public void OnStartupComplete(ref Array custom)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
}

I found a similar issue here but the solution didn't work for me as I am already building  for x64, and I am using 64 bit version of OneNote
I have tried to trace the error messages using Add in spy but it isn't picking up the Add-In. I have also tried looking at the Windows Event Viewer but there aren't any error messages there either.
I've also checked the registry values and the dll path seems to be correct, so I'm out of ideas on what could be going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated
